# how to push object ino an array when user inputs value in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple input fields under different headings:-

```
<label>User</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.username" name="arr[0]"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.userdob" name="arr[0]"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.userpanNo" name="arr[0]"/>

<label>Employee</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.empname" name="arr[1]"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.empdob" name="arr[1]"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.emppanNo" name="arr[1]"/>

<label>Daily Workers</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.dwname" name="arr[2]"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.dwdob" name="arr[2]"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.dwpanNo" name="arr[2]"/>
```

I want to save above data in the format:- `[{a.arr.username:any value},{a.arr.empname:any value},{a.arr.dwname:any value}]`. But the structure I am getting is:- `{a.arr.username:any value,a.arr.empname:any value,a.arr.dwname:any value}`.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you make some change to ng-model? making it like a.arr[i] will do it easily. If that will work, I can provide you the complete solution.

Comment: @Spidi'sWeb, no I don't want it like that

Answer (score 1):

Where you are storing data you will have to store it like :

```
a.arr=[];
//here you have to define object for each index before making keys of it.
a.arr[i]={};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var arr=[]; arr.push({'a.arr.username':$scope.a.arr.username,{'a.arr.empname':$scope.a.arr.empname}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to make your object as an array of it's properties. I suggest you to leave the code as it is and just add a code to make another controller property which will hold the array of those properties.

To get the array of properties, below code will help you:

```
var x = {username: "any value", empname: "any value", dwname: "any value"};
var newArr = [];
var properties = Object.keys(x);
for(var i=0;i<properties.length;i++){
    newArr.push({});
    newArr[newArr.length - 1][properties[i]] = x[properties[i]];
};
```

Let me know if you need to understand anything else regarding this.

Best Regards

Comment: will it make an array of objects like this:-[{a.arr.username:any value, a.arr.userdob:any value, a.arr.userpanNo: any vaue},{a.arr.empname:any value, a.arr.empdob:any value, a.arr.emppanNo: any vaue},{a.arr.dwname:any value, a.arr.dwdob:any value, a.arr.dwpanNo: any vaue}]

Comment: Yes

Just paste it to console and try running it. It will work.

Comment: it is creating objects for each properties

Comment: This is what you were asking in your question. Please let me know what exactly you need.